# resource file doesn't load anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unicode, mfc

I saved the .rc file of my project with Unicode encoding using visual studio 2010. I used Unicode - CodePage 1200 because this is what I think is the the format Visual Studio creates a fresh .rc file with when it is unicode enabled.

[image]

Now just working with the file normally in Visual Studio, at some point the .rc file becomes unreadable. When I run my application, it fails loading resources and never shows up. Even in Visual Studio I can't open the .rc file anymore. If I open it as text editor, it shows chinese characters all over but in reality it doesn't contain any chinese text.

My question is the how should I save a legacy .rc file with Unicode encoding so it supports international language? Any insight into why newly saved file works for some time but than stops working and even VS IDE can't open it?

Answer (score 0):

The [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) was most likely messed up.